# Confused about require JS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Consider the following example:

```
var ExampleFunction = function(param1, param2) {
   this.helloWorld = function() {
       console.log('hello world' + param1 + param2);
   }
}
```

When I do something like:

```
require(['https://path/to/example_function.js'], function(exampleFunction){
    console.log(exampleFunction);
});
```

I see:

```
define( function() { return function(param1, param2) {
    this.helloWorld = function() {
       console.log('hello world' + param1 + param2);
    }
} } );
```

How do I inject the dependencies of this function? I cannot seem to instantiate the function my self inject them via the call.

Also when loaded locally I can do:

`var exampleFunction = new ExampleFunction(someParam, someOtherParam);`

But when loaded rom the server I cannot.

**Ideas?**

Comment: do you have the example_function.js wrapped in define()?

Comment: No I don't I assume this is require js doing that. The code I posted above is the exact code on the server. Is require js wrapping it in define?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using scripts that aren't in the RequireJS format (wrapped in define()), you have to shim them in your require config so that they can be loaded properly:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "exampleFunction": "https://path/to/example_function.js"
    },

    shim: {
        "exampleFunction":      {
            exports:    "exampleFunction"
        }
    }
});
```

Then use them like so

```
require(["exampleFunction"], function(exampleFunction){
    new exampleFunction(param1, param2);
});
```

More on the subject http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: Could I still instantiate ExampleFunction to pass in the params in side the call back for require?

Comment: you should be able to do "new exampleFunction()" if that's what you mean

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serve an external file as a module, use the [`paths` config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths). The file path should be extensionless. Here's [an example from the docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pathsfallbacks):

```
requirejs.config({
    //To get timely, correct error triggers in IE, force a define/shim exports check.
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        jquery: [
            'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min',
            //If the CDN location fails, load from this location
            'lib/jquery'
        ]
    }
});

//Later
require(['jquery'], function ($) {

});
```

Comment: I am not following, can you give an example?

Comment: Ok how ever what if my function, as show above, takes arguments. Can I instantiate it to then pass in said arguments?